# parse date in golang

Tags: datetime, parsing, go

Please help me to parse date like `2018-12-17 12:55:50 +0300` in golang

I'm trying with layout

```
layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 +0000"
dateString := "2018-12-17 12:55:50 +0300"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, dateString)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error while parsing date :", err)
}
fmt.Println(t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
```

but compiler says `Error while parsing date : parsing time "2018-12-17 12:55:50 +0300" as "2006-01-02 15:04:05 +0000": cannot parse "300" as " +0000"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> import "time"
>
> the [layout] reference time can be thought of as
>
> ```
> 01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700
> ```

---

Use `-0700`, not `+0000`.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700"
    dateString := "2018-12-17 12:55:50 +0300"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, dateString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while parsing date :", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Xr8zaTjODgC

Output:

```
2018-12-17 12:55:50
```

Comment: This example works correctly and helps for me It's enough I think