# Convert timestamp to ISO format in golang

Tags: go, time, iso

I'm trying to convert the timestamp 2018-12-17T15:03:49.000+0000 to ISO format in golang, but am getting an error `cannot parse "+0000" as "Z07:00"`

This is what I tried

```
ts, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, currentTime)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That is not a Unix timestamp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: ok i edited the question

Comment: Try with -0700. It was asked a couple of days ago I think

Comment: what do you mean? @oren

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. You can take a look here - https://golang.org/pkg/time/. `RFC3339` doesn't include `+0000`, you're trying to format an invalid `currentTime` into `time.RFC3339`

Comment: I'm already asked it in that post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818026/parse-date-in-golang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
ts, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000+0000", currentTime)
```

since time.RFC3339 is just `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00`

Comment: You need `-0700` instead of `+0000`

Comment: @oren Doesn't that assume that he doesn't just want UTC?

Comment: not exactly, The doc says how to specify the custom layout. if you'll try to parse for example `2018-12-17T15:03:49.000+0100`. it will break. You can check my answer, i tried to be clear, since i myself just learning this stuff. In the end, the go doc is very detailed, and most of the answers are from there :)

Answer (score 9):

Beware, a long answer ahead

(tl;dr) use:

```
ts, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700", currentTime)
ts.Format(time.RFC3339)
```

---

I really like go documentation, and you should do :)

All from https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

```
RFC3339 = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
```

> Some valid layouts are invalid time values for time.Parse, due to
>   formats such as _ for space padding and Z for zone information

Which means you can't parse `+0000` with layout `Z07:00`.

Also:

> The reference time used in the layouts is the specific time:
>
> ```
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
> ```
>
> which is Unix time 1136239445. Since MST is GMT-0700, the reference
>   time can be thought of as
>
> ```
> 01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700
> ```

You can either parse numeric time zone offsets format as follows:

> ```
> -0700  ±hhmm
> -07:00 ±hh:mm
> -07    ±hh
> ```

Or replacing the sign in the format with a `Z`:

> ```
> Z0700  Z or ±hhmm
> Z07:00 Z or ±hh:mm
> Z07    Z or ±hh
> ```

### fraction:

From this go example https://play.golang.org/p/V9ubSN6gTdG

> // If the fraction in the layout is 9s, trailing zeros are dropped.
>
> ```
> do("9s for fraction", "15:04:05.99999999", "11:06:39.1234")
> ```

So you can parse it like:

```
ts, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999-0700", currentTime)
```

Also, From the doc

> A decimal point followed by one or more zeros represents a fractional
>   second, printed to the given number of decimal places. A decimal point
>   followed by one or more nines represents a fractional second, printed
>   to the given number of decimal places, with trailing zeros removed.
>   When parsing (only), the input may contain a fractional second field
>   immediately after the seconds field, **even if the layout does not**
>   **signify its presence**. **In that case a decimal point followed by a
>   maximal series of digits is parsed as a fractional second.**

Which means you can leave out the decimal points from the layout and it will parse correctly

```
ts, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700", currentTime)
```

For getting the time in `UTC` simply write `ts.UTC()`

And for formatting it to RFC3339, you can use

```
ts.Format(time.RFC3339)
```

### Example

```
currentTime := "2018-12-17T17:02:04.123+0530"
ts, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700", currentTime)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("ts:        ", ts)
fmt.Println("ts in utc: ", ts.UTC())
fmt.Println("RFC3339:   ", ts.Format(time.RFC3339))


// output
// ts:         2018-12-17 17:02:04.123 +0530 +0530
// ts in utc:  2018-12-17 11:32:04.123 +0000 UTC
// RFC3339:    2018-12-17T17:02:04+05:30
```

playground: https://play.golang.org/p/vfERDm_YINb